# Why is my google programmable search engine showing "no results"?

Tags: search-engine, google-search, google-custom-search

I used Google programmable search engine to create a custom search for my website but every time I search something that I know is on the website I get the response "no results" but ads appear. I added in my domain to google programmable search engine as shown below.
[*.mywebsite.com/* add in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xmE8.png)

I also integrated the given google code into my existing HTML file as shown/listed below.

```
<div class="search-head">
        <form class="search-bar" action="">
            <script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=30a4b4d6ce2b44870">
            </script>
            <div id="cse" style="width:20%; margin: 0; height: 10%; padding: 0;"></div>
            <div class="gcse-search"></div>

        </form>
</div>
```

[google code add in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbotQ.png)

Despite my best efforts and multiple hours of trying it, I cannot get any results.